# Position Content in a JS Reveal presentation using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, r-markdown, reveal.js

I want to write a block of javascript or JQuery that will push all of my content 50 pixels to the right, if I set a variable, "tree," to true. So far, my R markdown document looks like this:

```
<script>
var tree = true;
if (tree===true){
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").css(position,absolute);
  $("body").css(left,left+50);
  $("html").css(position,absolute);
  $("html").css(left,left+50)
  $("div.reveal").css(position,absolute);
  $("div.reveal").css(left,left+50)
  $("div.slides").css(position,absolute);
  $("div.slides").css(left,left+50)


});
}
</script>
```

When I Knit the code, the content displays in the same position that it did without the javascript. Is it possible to push my content 50 pixels to the right using this method? If not, how else can I accomplish this? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just set `<script> var tree = true; </script>` right after the YAML block?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I made that edit.

Comment: That is not what I meant. Anyways: It should be `if ( tree === true)`. `if ( tree = true)` will evaluate to `true` if `tree` is not true, because you are assigning a value inside the if condition.

Comment: A solution to your question would be to alter the default theme for the presentation (specifically the CSS properties you are modifying in your jQuery block) and save it as a new theme. Then you could offset your content by just using this slightly altered theme. Second options would be to just include a custom CSS file with the YAML `css` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to jQuery you could use `margin-left`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var tree = true;
if (tree===true){
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slides').css('margin-left', '50px');
});
}
</script>
```

From the following screenshot you can derive that all of the content (all slides) is contained within the `div` element that carries the class `.slides`:

[image]

With the script provided above the content moves the desired 50 pixels to the right (yellow area is the margin-left):

[image]